# Regex to check for date and time

Tags: java, regex

How to write a regex to check if the given format has only date/only time or both for the following format "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM AM" or "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM"

I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: You never answered my question from the previous post: *why* would you want to use a regex for this?

Comment: I'm sure there are going to be a thousand answers telling you to use '^\d{2}...' but this is a doomed approach. How are you going to guard against stupid input like 55:98PM, or validate that the day is valid for the given month? How are you going to cater for corner cases like leap years? Just use a date library and save yourself the hassle.

Comment: You've asked essentially the same question three times today, and I don't see much evidence that you have used the information that the community has already provided.  Hence, my downvote.  You have to work with us.  "It's the requirement" isn't a very good explanation.  Is this a homework problem, where you need to use a regex to demonstrate mastery of the tool?  If so, then please tag your question as homework.

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}(\s(A|P)M)?`

Comment: What if I enter 45 as the day? What if I enter 31 in a month that has only 30 days? What if I enter 29/02 in a non-leapyear? The problems with this approach are endless...

Comment: If you are going to have to call DateTime.TryParse afterwards to work out if its a valid date anyway, what's the point of using the regex?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Untested.

```
\b(\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}-\d{4} \d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}( (AM|PM))?)\b
```

Comment: Except this matches nonsense like 59-36-0000 43:54AM

Comment: I know. But if the target is to find dates in a text, this will do... I've never seen something like this in real life. If it is an assignment, they might test it for input like that yes...

Comment: A fair point. Though if this was being used to extract date-like substrings from unstructured text, I would suggest `\b` instead of `^$`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579461/872803 and manage `"dd-MM-yyy hh:mm"` :

```
if (myString.endsWith("AM") {
    // use "dd-MM-yyy hh:mm"
} else {
   // use "dd-MM-yyy HH:mm"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-\d{4} (20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})( (AM|PM))?)$
```

You got me on the leap year.